# C# how to make it efficient to list the directories on a ftp server

Tags: c#, list, ftp, directory

I need to get the content of the file list for files with a specific format from a ftp server. I have to read through all the directories and files, to check if it is or contains the file I need, then add the file into my file list. However, there are so many directories, subdirectories, and all kinds of files in the ftp server, it will be very time-consuming to do that. does anyone know how can i make it much more time efficient?

Comment: what you want is to get all files in a directories with specific format, i.e. `.txt` ?

Comment: Why does the FTP site make it so difficult? Ask the site admin for a login with exactly one folder and have them put your files in there. Usually those with the need to "read through all directories" for "files with a specific format" are up to something...

Comment: Yes, all the specific files i need should be only in one directory, unfortunately, the path of the directory varies from different machines, so we cannot hardcode the path of the directory, and need to search through all the directories and files in the server.

Comment: we are working for customers in semi-conductor industry, their ftp sites may have a different structure.

Comment: Then you could put the directories path into the App.Config. Then read it in you program, and `GetFiles` inside your path

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned that the directory path varies from machine to machine, you need to have a collection of all the machines and there directory paths. You need loop through the directory paths. Unfortunately you need to loop through every files (exclude the unwanted). Below is a pseudocode-

```
loop for each directory paths
    loop for each files in a directory paths by excluding unwanted files types
         store the required files in a collection
    end loop
end loop
return files
```

You may use parallel for loop (TPL in .Net) to execute the loops faster. Refer-

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Since there are different customers, and it is not possible for us to collect all the paths for all the machines for now. However, the parallel for loop you suggest may also help in some way, i need to do more researches. Thanks.